# Need help connecting my database to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect my database to my PHP code using this code:

```
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Landing page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    // Check if username and password are correct
    if ($_POST["username"] == "logintest" && $_POST["password"] == "access123!") {

    // If correct, we set the session to YES
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["logged_in"] = "YES";
      echo "<h1>You are now logged in</h1>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure1.php'>Link to protected file</a></p>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure2.php'>Link to protected file #2</a></p>";

    }
    else {

    // If not correct, we set the session to NO
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["logged_in"] = "NO";
      echo "<h1>You are NOT logged in </h1>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure1.php'>Link to protected file</a></p>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure2.php'>Link to protected file #2</a></p>";

    }

    ?>
    <p><a href="public.html">Public Page</a></p>
    <p><a href="logout.html">Logout</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Instead of using the inline username and password, I would like to use the databases username and password from a specific table. I just cant get it to work for some reason, and I am finding it really hard. It would be great if anyone could help.

Comment: can you please post your code ..

Comment: What is the name of your table? Also the columns for it?

Comment: Post your code in your question. This greatly increases your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: You can connect the database by `$con = mysql_connect('host','username','password');$con1 = mysql_select_db('db_name',$con);`

Comment: The database is called user_login, the table is users, and the columns are Username and Password

Comment: @papsk `mysql_` is deprecated, please don't recommend it's usage ;)

Comment: @peter ya i know:) but paddyward seems beginner that's y:)

Comment: @papsk then try to teach him correctly right away..

Comment: @peter i'm also learner and beginner...do not have the experience other than `mysql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Note:

- You have to establish first a connection to your database. Replace the necessary data inside the connection
- I used `mysqli_*` [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) rather than [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*`
- Replace your `if ($_POST["username"] == "logintest" && $_POST["password"] == "access123!") {` with `if($checklog > 0 ){`

**Code:**

```
/* ESTABLISH FIRST YOUR CONNECTION TO YOUR DATABASE */
$con = new mysqli("host", "User", "Password", "Database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM user_login WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?")){
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $checklog = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($checklog > 0){
      /* HERE IS YOUR CODE WITH SUCCESSFUL LOGIN */
    }
    else {
      /* HERE IS YOUR CODE WITH UNSUCCESSFUL LOGIN */
    }

  $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: You might also want to add some error code if your `$con->prepare` fails.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get the page to show who is logged in? For example, if they are logged in, it will display "Welcome [Firstname] [Lastname]"? Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to connect to MySQL. However, just knowing how to connect isn't enough. You need to learn how to use it as well. Therefor I'm first giving you a couple of links to MySQLi and PDO:

[PHP: MySQLi - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
[PHP: PDO - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Now to answer your question, here are some commonly used methods to connect to mysql:

**MySQLi Object Oriëntated Style**

```
<?php

$dbhost = ""; //Server Address
$dbname = ""; //Database Name
$dbuser = ""; //Database User
$dbpass = ""; //Database Password

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

?>
```

**MySQLi Procedural Style**

```
<?php

$dbhost = ""; //Server Address
$dbname = ""; //Database Name
$dbuser = ""; //Database User
$dbpass = ""; //Database Password

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . mysqli_connect_error() . ")";
}

?>
```

**PDO Object Oriëntated Style**

```
<?php

$dbhost = ""; //Server Address
$dbname = ""; //Database Name
$dbuser = ""; //Database User
$dbpass = ""; //Database Password

$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```